# convert xmlhttp.response text to json and print (Explanation in detail with error)?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp

Here in the below code I want my xmlhttp.responseText to be  converted into JSON object and print it to html element name "deta" 
on running the below code i get my data printed in console but html page is not reflected. ?

I get my data printed on html page by using xmlhttp.responseText but after converting it to json it throws error

Following Error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 12
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange ((index):112)

JS:

```
function myFunction() {


  var name = document.getElementById("ab").value;

  var urls = "time.jsp?name=" + name;

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  // code for IE6, IE5
  else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

      var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById("deta").innerHTML = a;
      // want  data be printed in "deta" html element

    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", urls, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML

```html
<input type="text" id="ab" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

JSP

```
JSP code --------------------------------------------

<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%
        try
    {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  * FROM student WHERE  name = ?"); 
                String name=request.getParameter("name");
                ps.setString(1, name);
                ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();

              ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
              int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

               if(res.first())
                {

                     String str= res.getString(1)+"  "+res.getString(2)+"  "+res.getString(3)+"  "+res.getString(4)+"  "+res.getString(5);  
                    out.print(str) ;

                }else
                {

                    out.print("Name not valid");
                }
                con.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);  
            }
    finally
    {

    }
    %>
```

Comment: Show the JSON...

Comment: var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);        
          document.getElementById("deta").innerHTML=a;

Comment: SHOW THE JSON! `{  "bla":"R IN THE WRONG POISITION" }`

Comment: Check that your JSON is well formatted.  For example `{red : "test"}` is not while `{"red" : "test"}` is